# Python list updating itself

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Well this is kind of an elementary question, but here it goes:

Consider the following code:

```
listA = ['a','b','c']
listB = listA
listB.pop(0)
print listB
print listA
```

The output comes as:

```
['b','c']
['b','c']
```

However, shouldn't the output be:

```
['b','c']
['a','b','c']
```

What exactly is happening here? And how could I get the expected output? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is happening is that `listA` and `listB` are two names for the same list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `listB` is nothing but a reference to `listA`. If you want a copy of `listA` you can issue

```
listB = listA[:]
```

for a shallow copy or

```
import copy
listB = copy.deepcopy(listA)
```

for a deep copy. [Here](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php) is a good read on the topic.